# Rename VIP User card to Expanded User card on new profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, privileges, user-card

My next privilege is 1000 - I get the vote count and a VIP usercard:

> [image: Next privilege from profile screenshot]

HU? VIP usercard? [Privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/) doesn't say anything:

> [image: Privileges page 1000 rep section]

Ahh, a Help Centre search comes up with the [Expanded usercard section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user):

> [image: Help centre Expanded usercard section]

But the letters VIP are not mentioned anywhere on that page (I did a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>).

This is the only place I saw the phrase VIP usercard - and it doesn't even fit in. I think this should be changed to Expanded usercard - or even dropped completely.